# Filter nested json based on two conditions

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I have a nested json array as below:

```
[  
   {  
      "filename":"Vegetable",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "filename":"Juicy",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "filename":"Tomato",
                  "type":"ts1"
               },
               {  
                  "filename":"Carrot",
                  "type":"ts2"
               },
               ,
               {  
                  "filename":"Onion",
                  "type":"ts3"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Sweet",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "filename":"Potato",
                  "type":"ts4"
               },
               {  
                  "filename":"Water melon",
                  "type":"ts"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   { filename:"Fruits"..........
   },....
]
```

I need to filter the array in such a way that below conditions:

1. Filename = Juicy  given(it can be Sweet as well i mean i that level 2nd level of array)
2. Under that will have a filter text suppose it is `'t'`. Then it should match file names `Tomato, Carrot` since it contains `t`

Bases on conditions below the expected result is

```
[  
   {  
      "filename":"Vegetable",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "filename":"Juicy",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "filename":"Tomato",
                  "type":"ts1"
               },
               {  
                  "filename":"Carrot",
                  "type":"ts2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Sweet",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "filename":"Potato",
                  "type":"ts4"
               },
               {  
                  "filename":"Water melon",
                  "type":"ts"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   { filename:"Fruits"..........
   },....
]
```

ie it should eleminate

```
{  "filename":"Onion",
   "type":"ts3"
 }
```

Since onion don't contain 't'.

I have tried with filter, map using arrow functions but not working as expected.

I have tried function `filterby =(childname, filterText).filter =>{...}`

Please guide me...

Comment: Can you explain a bit better the first condition ?

Comment: The expected output has both `Sweet` and `Juicy`. Can your clarify what you mean by *"Filename:Juicy ----> Which can be Sweet"*

Comment: @ Teneff updated

Comment: @ adiga updated question for more clarity

Comment: So is the variable is just the letter `t`?

Comment: @adiga t is third level under juicy array sub array 3 of them in that t contains only in tomato and potato not in onion hope u are clear

Comment: I understood that bit. What exactly is the first filter? I'm guessing you'll send either `Juicy` or `Sweet` in a parameter `fileName`. Why does the output have both?

Comment: @adiga Juicy is to identify which sub array we need to filter. It should filter sub array under that part only not other

Comment: If the input is `Juicy`, the output will not have the `"filename":"Sweet"` object, correct? Your expected output has both of them. That's why I'm clarifying

Comment: !adiga if "filename":"Juicy" then it should filter its sub -array and rest of the array i mean sweet should be untouched please check expected array so u get the clear picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come with one solution that uses two nested [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) at the last level of childrens:

```js
const input = [  
 {  
   "filename":"Vegetable",
   "children":[  
     {  
       "filename":"Juicy",
       "children":[  
         {"filename":"Tomato", "type":"ts1"},
         {"filename":"Carrot", "type":"ts2"},
         {"filename":"Onion", "type":"ts3"}
       ]
     },
     {  
       "filename":"Sweet",
       "children":[  
         {"filename":"Potato", "type":"ts4"},
         {"filename":"Water melon", "type":"ts"}
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "filename":"Fruits",
   "children": []
 }
];

const filterBy = (arr, childname, filterText) =>
{
    return arr.map(({filename, children}) =>
    {
        return {filename, children: children.map(({filename, children}) =>
        {
           if (filename === childname)
               return {filename, children: children.filter(
                   x => x.filename.match(filterText)
               )};
           else
               return {filename, children};
        })};
    });
}

console.log(
  "Filter the Juits by text 't': ",
  filterBy(input, "Juicy", "t")
);

console.log(
  "Filter the Sweet by text 'r': ",
  filterBy(input, "Sweet", "r")
);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: @androidGenX You are welcome, some mistakes were fixed on the updates. Also, I believe there could be a simpler solution if you use a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/). Maybe someone comes with an answer using it on the future.